# Gigya - Notify I've logged wih Facebook

Tags: android, facebook-login, gigya

**Answered on the comment below:** [Gigya - Notify I've logged wih Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43759249/gigya-notify-ive-logged-wih-facebook/43762254?noredirect=1#comment74606365_43762254)

I'm using the Gigya service to offer social login in my client Android application. The problem is that the Facebook one has to be native, so I've edited a little bit the data flow.

First steps:
Add to my `AndroidManifest.xml` the Gigya and Facebook activities:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.gigya.socialize.android.ui.HostActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
<activity
    android:name="com.gigya.socialize.android.login.providers.WebLoginActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:allowTaskReparenting="true" >
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
       <data android:scheme="com.company.appname" android:host="gsapi" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="{myFacebookAppId}"/>
```

After that, in my `MainActivity.java` I initialize Gigya:

```
GSAPI.getInstance().initialize(MainActivity.this, gigyaApiKey, gigyaServer);
GSAPI.getInstance().setSocializeEventListener(new GigyaSocializeListener(MainActivity.this));
GSAPI.getInstance().setAccountsEventListener(new GigyaAccountsListener());
```

Then in my `LoginGigyaWebViewFragment` I load in a `WebView` an url where is the Gigya webView (email and password `EditText` and Social Plugin), intercepting the request url and doing the native Facebook login.

```
public class LoginGigyaWebViewFragment extends Fragment {

    private final static String TAG = LoginGigyaWebViewFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private WebView webView;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login_gigya_webview, container, false);
        webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.login_gigya_webView);
        setupWebView();
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.mywebpagedomain.com/gigya/tablet.html");
        return view;
    }

    private void setupWebView() {
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {            
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                String provider = uri.getQueryParameter("x_provider");
                if (provider != null && !provider.isEmpty()) {
                    switch (provider) {
                        case "facebook":
                            webView.stopLoading();
                            makeFacebookStuff();
                            return false;
                        default:
                            return GSWebBridge.handleUrl(webView, url);
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        GSWebBridge.attach(getActivity(), webView, new GSWebBridgeListener() {
            @Override
            public void beforeLogin(WebView webView, GSLoginRequest.LoginRequestType requestType, GSObject params) {
                Log.d(TAG, "beforeLogin");
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoginResponse(WebView webView, GSResponse response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onLoginResponse");
            }

            @Override
            public void onPluginEvent(WebView webView, GSObject gsObject, String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onPluginEvent");
            }
        });
    }

    private void makeFacebookStuff() {
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getContext().getApplicationContext());
        FacebookSdk.setApplicationId(AppConfig.getInstance().getFacebookAppId());
        LoginManager.getInstance().setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.NATIVE_WITH_FALLBACK);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.d("Facebook", loginResult.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d("Facebook", "onCancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.d("Facebook", error.toString());
            }
        });
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (GSAPI.getInstance().handleAndroidPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that even the Facebook login succes, I don't know how to notify Gigya that happened. Another solution I've been thinking about is login in Gigya manually with the Facebook userId or Facebook email, but I don't know how to do that.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook native login is supported. In order to use Facebook native login with Gigya, you need to to install the Facebook SDK for Android into your app as a dependency and recompile it. You can see detailed instructions here: http://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/Android#Android-AddingFacebookNativeLogin

Comment: Sorry for the lack of code. I've updated it as it was since the beginning.

Comment: Oscar, unfortunately, you can not add native login _on top_ of the Gigya SDK. When you install the Gigya SDK and the Facebook SDK as described in the above link; Facebook native login is added directly into the Gigya login, so when users click on the Facebook link, they are automatically directed to Native login -- and the Gigya session is started without any additional effort (after a successful login). Trying to implement this any other way is not supported, as to support native login, it has to be configured at build time inside the Gigya SDK.

Comment: Ah, ok. Understood. So I guess my next task is thinking about how to change my login screen automatically when I login with Facebook and how to access to the Gigya data. Thank you very much!